# how to predict the time series data with two target outputs

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, statistics

I am a newbie to time series problems, I am doing one of the time series problems, I a have 317 columns and, I need to predict the stock Revenue and Price, I am trying to do it, but the many columns contain more 0's and some of the info values,
please help me how to solve it.

Comment: If i understood your question right i guess Hierarchical time series is the answer for your question; check out this: https://otexts.com/fpp2/hierarchical.html to know more about Hierarchical time series